# \smash all inline math

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, inline

Occasionally, I have inline math in my text (e.g., `$Y^{(0)}$`). This will make the line on which it appears taller and introduce an extra space between that line and the previous one. This has the undesired effect of making that line stand out. The solution is to use `\smash{$Y^{(0)}$}` instead. But I don't want to have to do this manually for all the inline math that I have.

So, is there a way to `\smash` everything by default? I.e., I want my line height to be fixed and not adjust to things like `$Y^{(0)}$`.

Comment: In general, your default line height should be able to accomodate `$Y^{(0)}$` without `\smash`ing.  So perhaps a small sample code to demonstrate the issue would help.

Comment: just to confirm you want the (0) to over-print the line above rather than (say) reduce height of superscripts or make the default baseline spacing large enough? (the two options a normally seem safer)

Comment: I'm using `emulateapj`, which is fairly tight, so `$Y^{(0)}$` does require `\smash`ing. And yes, I want the superscript to over-print and possibly overlap with the line above (just like `\smash` would do). http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86747/how-does-one-stop-automatic-line-spacing-increases-when-typesetting-tall-math-sy might indeed be a duplicate, but trying that solution messes up all my `align` environment and introduces an enormous amount of vertical whitespace for each of them.

Comment: since you have some important considerations that render the cited question unusable, it would help if you edited them into the text of your question -- that would help keep it from getting closed inadvisedly.  it would help if you refer to that question in your edit and say why it doesn't work for you.